# How to have float left and right together

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

I don't understand why the Item 1 move the float right side of floats and more,

I wrote a little example to explain that : [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4cvaU/)

**HTML:**

Simple html structure

```
<div class="span12">
    <div id="accordion">
    <div class="item">
    <div class="title">ITEM 1</div>
            <div>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec sed odio dui. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="title">ITEM 2</div>
            <div>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec sed odio dui. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="title">ITEM 3</div>
            <div>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec sed odio dui. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="title">ITEM 4</div>
            <div>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec sed odio dui. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

I just active accordion from jQuery UI

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    'header': '.title',
        'active': false,
        'collapsible': true
});
```

**CSS**

CSS to float N+1 to the right with 1 accordion per line right side and 1 per line left side

```
.span12{
width:100%
}
.span12 .item{
width:35%
}
.span12 .item:nth-child(odd){
float:left;clear:left
}
.span12 .item:nth-child(even){
float:right;clear:right
}
.span12 .clear{
clear:both
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the drop-down absolute then.

```
.item  { position: relative; }
.ui-accordion-content { position: absolute;top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 5; }
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cvaU/8/)

Comment: But when Item 2 is open, the left side is downed, i want to have separate behavior. (Thanks for help)

Comment: I tried with css because i've not logic control over the template

Comment: Okey how about something like this then: http://jsfiddle.net/4cvaU/8/ I will update the answer showing the important points.